# Yii dataprovider 3 tables

Tags: mysql, yii, clistview

I want this:

```
SELECT i.inmueble_nombre, a.arrendatario_nombre, a.arrendatario_email, c.contrato_fecha_ini, c.contrato_fecha_fin
FROM zf_inmuebles i, zf_arrendatarios a, zf_contratos c
WHERE c.contrato_estado =  'ALta'
AND i.inmueble_id = c.zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id
AND a.arrendatario_id = c.zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id
```

In a dataprovider for a Clistview, how can I do it?

Comment: do you have 3 models with relations in each models?

Comment: i have 1 model for each table

Comment: but they are not related I wanted to do by hand :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to use a [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider). Basicaly, you just set the query and the count, and the data provider will return an array (with your selected columns as keys) for each list item.

Comment: and how i call the data? $data->i.inmueble_id?

Comment: Something like $data[ 'inmueble_id' ]. Actually, I'm not sure about the key in your case. I recommend you to do the SELECT with "AS" (ex: SELECT i.inmueble_nombre AS nombre)

Comment: If you don't want to use "AS", print the $data with CVarDumper:dump( $data, 10, true ) to see the keys.

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::encode($data['inmueble_nombre']);?> I put all like that but this is the problem:Undefined index: id

Comment: protected function fetchKeys()
116     {
117         $keys=array();
118         if($data=$this->getData())
119         {
120             if(is_object(reset($data)))
121                 foreach($data as $i=>$item)
122                     $keys[$i]=$item->{$this->keyField};
123             else
124                 foreach($data as $i=>$item)
125                     $keys[$i]=$item[$this->keyField];
126         }
127         return $keys;
128     }

Comment: It works! like this $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,array('keyField' =>'inmueble_id','pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1))); But pagination is not displaying, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

In controller.

```
    $sql = "SELECT i.inmueble_nombre, a.arrendatario_nombre, a.arrendatario_email, c.contrato_fecha_ini, c.contrato_fecha_fin
    FROM zf_inmuebles i, zf_arrendatarios a, zf_contratos c
    WHERE c.contrato_estado =  'ALta'
    AND i.inmueble_id = c.zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id
    AND a.arrendatario_id = c.zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id";

    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,array(
    'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=> '10', //no of record per page here
    ),);
$this->render('VIEW_NAME', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

In VIEW_FILE

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',

            array(
                      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                      'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
                      'columns'=>array(
                      array('header'=>'Inmueble Nombre','name'=>'inmueble_nombre'),  
                      array('header'=>'Arrendatario Nombre','name'=>'arrendatario_nombre'), 

),
));
```

Comment: Please check your questions. You asked for clistview only

Comment: It works! like this $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,array('keyField' =>'inmueble_id','pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1))); But pagination is not displaying, why?

Comment: the field "columns" doesnt work in CListview, thats what i mean

Comment: Ok. I understood. So now everythng is working except pagination?

Comment: yep, pagination doesnt display

Comment: for pagination to work, you must provide totalItemCount to CSqlDataProvider - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#totalItemCount-detail